# Outlook 365 with Two sidebar plugins showing on top of eachother

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, plugins

I am using Outlook from Office 365.  I use two productivity plugins: Hubspot and Grammarly.  Unfortunately, both of these plugins have a sidebar that occupies the same space on the right side of the message window and they don't display next to each other, they display on top of each other.  Hubspot usually wins out and is displayed on the top effectively making Grammarly unusable.

Does anyone know how to get these two plugins to be nice to each other and work together?  I can't be the only person using both of these productivity tools.

Best wishes,
Nate

Comment: Outlook doesn't do the job to make the 3rd-party add-ins work together. You have to contact the provider of the add-ins or use the workaround you have found to just use one add-in sidebar at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround as soon as I posted: 
https://community.hubspot.com/t5/Outlook-Sales-Extension/Conflict-with-Grammarly-and-Hubspot-Sales-outlook-add-on/td-p/213909

The workaround is to turn off the HubSpot sidebar when you want to use Grammarly.  Not ideal, but a start.